# Toggle a custom icon on an Action Button on Lotus Notes form

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

When editing the action button properties, it allows an @if statement to flip/flop two choices (lock/unlock). i.e. `@If(enlock=1;"Unlock";"Lock")` for the "Label" of the action button.
At the bottom of the Action properties, icons can be None, Notes, or Custom. When I select Custom, I want the @if to use either the Locked/Unlocked Notes icons. (actn084.gif and actn085.gif, respectively) Or numbers #62 (locked) and #(I don't know/can't find, the # for the unlock icon).
I've tried formula with the icon number, like in a view, "display as icons" for view column. Using an @if, I've tried the gif on local and server replica's and it didn't give any results.
Please see the example image below.

Image example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBac3.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to add actn084.gif and actn085.gif to **Resources/Images**.

[image]

Then, you can use a formula

```
@If(enlock=1;"actn085.gif";"actn084.gif")
```

for calculating icon.

As an **alternative**, you could create **two buttons** and **hide-when** them depending on field enlock. You could assign label and icon direct to buttons without formula then.

The hide formula would be `enlock=1` for first button and `enlock!=1` for the second. In both buttons you would have to add `@Command([RefreshHideFormulas]);` at the end of your action formula to refresh the action buttons (or `Call uiDoc.RefreshHideFormulas` for LotusScript action code).

Comment: I had been using two action buttons, one each for lock and unlock. I incorporated the actions into a single button with the intent of cutting down on clutter. I named the action button Toggle and used the Label to show accordingly.